# How clean the url in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following structure:
`http://website.com/dir1/dir2/article.php?id=315&lang=EN`

I would like the above to appear as:
`http://website.com/dir1/article/315/`

How can this be accomplished in .htaccess? Also, is there a good tutorial on the net that goes through different scenarios and explains this clearly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/dir2/$2.php?id=$3&lang=EN [L,QSA]
```

**Fot tutorial on mod_rewrite:** Start with www.easymodrewrite.com then search on Google for more.